# Al publicar mi paquete de python con recursos no los instala de forma correcta

Tags: python, pip

Buen día,

Cree un paquete para distribuir y necesito unas imágenes SVG como recursos, el archivo MANIFEST.in tiene lo siguiente (El MANIFEST.in lo hice con ayuda del paquete `check-manifest`)

```
include *.in
include *.toml
recursive-include src *.svg
```

La carpeta donde tengo el paquete tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
FolderBase
|- build
|- dist
|- src
|  |- paquete
|  |  |- __pycache__
|  |  |- img
|  |  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |  |- img1.svg
|  |  |  |- img2.svg
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- paquete.py
|  |- paquete.egg-info
|- tests
|- .gitignore
|- LICENSE
|- MANIFEST.in
|- README.md
|- setup.py
|- tox.ini
```

Como se puede ver, las imágenes están en la carpeta "img" dentro del folder del paquete

Al hacer pruebas locales utilizando `pip install -e .` el paquete funciona de forma correcta y muestra las imágenes, pero al instalar el paquete que está en distribución dice que las imágenes no se pueden encontrar y si reviso dentro de `site-packages` en la carpeta de mi paquete puedo ver que el folder "img" si existe, pero las imágenes no están dentro.

La primera versión que publiqué tenía la siguiente estructura (El folder del paquete y el de "img" están a la misma "altura" dentro de "src")

```
FolderBase
|- build
|- dist
|- src
|  |- paquete
|  |  |- __pycache__
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- paquete.py
|  |- paquete.egg-info
|  |- img
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- img1.svg
|  |  |- img2.svg
|- tests
|- .gitignore
|- LICENSE
|- MANIFEST.in
|- README.md
|- setup.py
|- tox.ini
```

Al publicar el paquete con esta estructura (El contenido de MANIFEST.in es el mismo en ambos casos) las imágenes si se muestran pero al revisar la carpeta `site-packages` puedo ver el folder de mi paquete, pero también existe la carpeta "img" con mis recursos y creo que no es conveniente ya que si en algún momento instalo otro paquete que tenga por nombre "img" entonces todos mis recursos se borrarían.

Por más que he buscado no encuentro como hacer que la carpeta con recursos esté dentro de la carpeta "src" y que al instalarse el paquete, los recursos estén disponibles. Creo que hace falta algo en el archivo MANIFEST.in pero no estoy seguro de qué es, ¿Alguien me puede orientar? Lo que deseo es que al instalar tenga la carpeta de mi paquete y adentro tenga la carpeta "img" con las imágenes SVG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día,

Por fin pude encontrar una respuesta.

Es importante que el archivo `MANIFEST.in` tenga declarada la siguiente línea

```
recursive-include src *.svg
```

De esa forma se indica que cualquier archivo SVG encontrado dentro de la carpeta "src" (Y sub carpetas) se incluya en el paquete de instalación. Si se desean archivos con cualquier otra extensión se deben incluir de forma similar (Por ejemplo `recursive-include src *.png` incluye archivos PNG)

La forma más fácil de incluir los recursos es agregar `include_package_data` en `setup.py`.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Otra opción es guardarlos como `base64 encoded strings` en algún archivo de python, por ejemplo `img.py` (Dependiendo del formato de la imagen)

```
img1 = "<ALGUNB64ENCODED_STR>"
img2 = "<ALGUNB64ENCODED_STR>"
```

Y en el archivo `py` raíz del paquete importar el archivo `img`. En este caso no se necesitaría la línea `recursive-include src *.svg` en `MANIFEST.in` pero es importante que `setup.py` tenga la siguiente configuración para poder incluir todos los archivos `py` de la carpeta "src" (Y subcarpetas)

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},
    packages = find_packages(where='src'),
    ...
)
```